# Perfered method for removing Roslyn folder from Octopus deploy nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, octopus-deploy

I've noticed that octopack is including the Roslyn folder under the bin folder for my web deployment.  What would be the preferred method for excluding this from the build without affecting development.  I considered a post build event in only the "release" solution config to delete it but wondered if there was a better way (and it doesn't need to be specific to octopus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder is added by the [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform) nuget package. If you want C#6 support in Asp.Net (.cshtml or .aspx) files it needs to be there, because the roslyn's csc.exe from that folder is used to compile your views.

In order to be able to remove it (not deploy it), you'd need to [precompile your web application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228015(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`aspnet_compiler.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx)